# UPDATE and SELECT

Tags: sql, database, select, updates, privileges

Why do I need the SELECT privilege on this:

```
UPDATE Sailors S SET 
S.rating = S.rating - 1
```

While I don't need it for this query:

```
 UPDATE Sailors S
 SET S.rating = 8
```

Comment: I am guessing that depends on the database (in practice, anyone with update privileges has select privileges).  But the first query has to read a value, so that may be the reason why.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first you are selecting

```
= S.rating - 1
```

In the second you are not selecting

```
= 8
```

[sp_table_privileges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173835.aspx)

> SELECT = GRANTEE can retrieve data for one or more of the columns.
>
> INSERT = GRANTEE can provide data for new rows for one or more of the  columns.
>
> UPDATE = GRANTEE can modify existing data for one or more of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

In the first, you're essentially setting S.rating = `SELECT S.rating - 1 FROM Sailors S`

In the second you're just setting S.rating = a value (8)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're reading from S in the first query (the second S.rating) where as in the second query you're only ever writing data to S.  To read data you will need SELECT permissions.

Answer (score 0):

in first 'S.rating -1' this is unknown to Oracle and oracle engine goes to the table refer by alias S (its sailors in your case) and 

a)query rating from it and 

b)then subtract 1 from it 

 for point a it requires select privilege.